# Dreaded AADSTS50011 reply url error for web app login using Azure AD - runs fine on localhost

Tags: azure-active-directory

Had a C# LoB test app authenticating and authorising nicely using Azure AD with a reply url of /signing-oidc

Suddenly it's stopped validating, and the dreaded AADSTS50011 url error comes up.

I can't figure out why this has changed?

Using Microsoft.Identity.Web with the following startup.cs ConfigureServices and Configure methods:

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

        services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration);
            //.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi();

        services.AddControllersWithViews(options => {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        });


        services.AddRazorPages().AddMvcOptions(options => {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                          .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                          .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        }).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

        services.AddServerSideBlazor(o => o.DetailedErrors = true);
        services.AddScoped<IGpsDataService, GpsDataService>();
        services.AddTelerikBlazor();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
        if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            endpoints.MapControllers();

            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        });
    }
```

Pretty much boilerplate.

Can anyone point me to the correct callback url? I have it as /signin-oidc and that's configured in the appsettings.json file and on the Azure AD app authentication settings.

Stumped. Runs fine on localhost, but not in Azure ‍♂️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To deal with this kind of problem, you can try a general solution:

When you visit the application url , you will be redirected to the login page. Decode the authorization request url, you will find `redirect_url`, copy the value of `redirect_url` and paste it into the azure portal, and try again.

[image]

For the redirect URL, it should start with https, if you need to start with `http`, you must configure it as `http://localhost`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Solved!