# Spring Security Azure AD redirect url issue

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, spring-security-oauth2

When I try running in localhost, it works fine. But when I try running the same behind a load balancer, it gives the following error:

```
AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application: '<clien-id>'.
```

I have registered the application at AzureAD with the load balancer URL. But when I send my request, the redirect URL is still localhost as shown below.

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=XXX&...**redirect_uri=localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/azure**&nonce=...

I want my application to insert the load balancer URL as the value of redirect_url (instead of localhost).

I tried the solutions suggested below and still not successful:

[Redirect URL for Spring OAuth2 app on Azure with Active Directory: Invalid Redirect URI Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60365017/redirect-url-for-spring-oauth2-app-on-azure-with-active-directory-invalid-redir)

[Spring Boot using Azure OAuth2 - reply URL does not match error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66065527/spring-boot-using-azure-oauth2-reply-url-does-not-match-error)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this help you?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67056387/dreaded-aadsts50011-reply-url-error-for-web-app-login-using-azure-ad-runs-fine/67056612#67056612

Comment: Thanks Carl. I decoded and that's what I pasted below. I need some way where this can be customized in my Java Spring boot application.

Comment: You need to change the redirect_uri in both Azure portal and your code. If the two URLs are not the same, the error will occur.

Comment: Yes I checked may times, but it seems OK. Still trying..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you use a load balancer/proxy, you need to add some extra configuration to make it possible to resolve the redirect URL correctly.

A load balancer usually applies the standard [RFC7239 "Forwarded Headers"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7239) like `X-Forwarded-Proto` and `X-Forwarded-Host`. In that case, the redirect url should be correctly computed after applying the following two configurations. (Example for the Tomcat scenario)

```
server.forward-headers-strategy=NATIVE
```

> "If the proxy adds the commonly used X-Forwarded-For and
> X-Forwarded-Proto headers, setting server.forward-headers-strategy to
> NATIVE is enough to support those."

```
server.tomcat.redirect-context-root=false
```

> If you are using Tomcat and terminating SSL at the proxy,
> server.tomcat.redirect-context-root should be set to false. This
> allows the X-Forwarded-Proto header to be honored before any redirects
> are performed.

The above configuration works if you use a placeholder for the base URL in your client configuration in Spring Security, for example `{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}`. In this way, the `{baseUrl}` placeholder is dynamically resolved by Spring Security differently depending on whether it's behind a load balancer or not (`https://your-lb-url.com` vs `http://localhost:8080`).

More info in the official documentation:

- [Spring Boot - Running Behind a Front-end Proxy Server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-behind-a-proxy-server)
- [Spring Security - Proxy Server Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#http-proxy-server)

Comment: Well, there were multiple issues. The URL configured had a space - a typo. In application.properties, had to add the following: spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.redirect-uri=<LB URL with https://>